# php file_put_contents('php script.php','/tmp/tmpOut.html') says "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Tags: php, bash

my PHP-Script <sup>1</sup> can be started with or without parameters. Results are sent as HTML. I would like to redirect / save these results in a file.

I tried

```
/usr/bin/php7.4 file_put_contents('/usr/bin/php7.4 SL5_preg_contentFinder/SL5_preg_contentFinder.php','/tmp/tempOut.html')

/usr/bin/php7.4 file_put_contents("/usr/bin/php7.4 SL5_preg_contentFinder/SL5_preg_contentFinder.php","/tmp/tempOut.html")

Error unexpected token `('

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

and tried

```
/usr/bin/php7.4 SL5_preg_contentFinder/SL5_preg_contentFinder.php "" > ./results-tmp.html

# Error Parameter must be an array

> PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/m/GolandProjects/php2go-translator/SL5_preg_contentFinder/SL5_preg_contentFinder.php on line 1698
```

---

System:

running in Kubuntu and have installed two versions of PHP

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2020 15:47:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

$ php5.6 --version
PHP 5.6.40-38+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

1: PHP-Script [SL5_preg_contentFinder.php](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sl5net/SL5_preg_contentFinder/master/SL5_preg_contentFinder.php)

Comment: The second invocation is correct (if you want to pass an empty argument), and the warning is a bug in your php script.

Comment: This is hard to debug without a proper backtrace. From what I can spot without having dug deep, your variable `private $foundPos_list;` is undefined (`NULL`) upon declaration. If you don't set it anywhere (which is probably what happened, or you set the wrong scalar type), a `count()` on it will fail.

Comment: @thatotherguy works. thanks

Comment: You can't use PHP statements as shell commands.